# Using user input to generate suggestion

Tags: css, html

Im totally new at programming and in my class we are faced with the challenge to code a website using html5 and CSS during the semester.

I am wondering if this idea is possible to code in only html5:

My idea is to generate movies/series based on what the user says it likes. My idea is that the user would get 5-10 options to click and when they are done choosing what the want to click they would click "generate" and they would get suggestions based on what they like.

It is based on netflix:s own series and movies and i thought I would personally "tag" the movies with terms like "action" "drama" "netflix rating" so I dont have to "get" information from some server.

what is the best way to save the movies/series with picture and info about the movie and the tags i personally made?
Is this idea very hard, very easy, medium? Is it possible for a new programmer to do?

So for example:

Would you like to watch a movie or series?

MOVIE - SERIE

What genre do you want to watch?

ACTION - COMEDY - DRAMA

what Netflix rating would you want?

1-2 stars - 3-4 starts - 5 stars

"GENERATE"

Comment: This question is far too broad to be usefully answered here, there are whole books written on this subject. You will, I'm afraid, have to undertake some of your own research as what you think the best methods might be, try and implement them and come back with specific questions when, or if, those attempted solutions/approaches don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following data model :

```
var media = [
    {
        title: 'Shaolin Soccer',
        type: 'movie',
        genre: 'comedy',
        rating: 4
    },
    {
        title: 'Mr. Robot',
        type: 'serie',
        genre: 'dunno',
        rating: 9
    },
    {
        title: 'Star Wars'
        type: 'movie',
        genre: 'sci-fi',
        rating: 7.5
    }
    // ...
];
```

All you need to do is to filter the `media` array in order to remove all the elements that don't match the user's choices. Say for example you have 3 drop-down inputs for the 3 questions

```
<form id="choices">
    <select name="type" id="choice-type">
        <option value="">Movie or Serie</option>
        <option value="movie">Movie</option>
        <option value="serie">Serie</option>
    </select>

    <select name="type" id="choice-genre">
        <option value="">Genre</option>
        <option value="comedy">comedy</option>
        <option value="dunno">dunno</option>
        <option value="sci-fi">sci-fi</option>
    </select>

    <select name="rating" id="choice-rating">
        <option value="">Rating</option>
        <option value="1-2">1-2 stars</option>
        <option value="3-4">3-4 starts</option>
        <option value="5-5">5 stars</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="generate suggestions" />
</form>

<ul id="suggestions">

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById('choices').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var type = document.getElementById('choice-type').value;
        var genre = document.getElementById('choice-genre').value;
        var rating = document.getElementById('choice-rating').value.split('-');
        var suggestions = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
            if (media[i].type == type && media[i].genre == genre && media[i].rating >= rating[0] && media[i].rating <= rating[1])
                suggestions.push(media[i])
        }

        var destination = document.getElementById('suggestions');
        destination.innerHTML = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = suggestions[i].title;
            destination.appendChild(li);
        }

    });
</script>
```